# What to set widths to if i how much space between peaks is irrelevant to if a point is a peak or not? [scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt]

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html

I see that the widths parameter is supposed to be an array of distances you expect peaks to be. Is this correct? If this is true what should i set this too if for my particular problem, the distance between peaks is irrelevant to whether or not that data point should be considered a peak or not.

Answer (score 0):

`widths` gives the range of peak widths.  You have an equivalent interpretation, I think.  For instance, given

```
 1  2  5  9  8  9  8  9  7  4  2  1
```

Do you have one peak (width >= 4), two (3 <= width < 4), or three (width < 3)?

Your question implies that you consider this to be three peaks, in which case you can set `widths` to a pair of unit values (ones).  However, note that if this is, indeed, your case, then you can use a much simpler algorithm.  Simply iterate down the list, looking for values a[i] which are more than the neighboring values.  If you have a convenient `shift` operator, you can convert to a pair of boolean arrays to denote rising and falling values.  Where you have matching `True` values, you have a peak.

Comment: Are you saying that widths is the width of the actual peak then? Not the distance between peaks. Ie. if you supplied a widths of only [5], then a peak is actually 5 units?

Comment: Right.  You have to read through the documentation to get the distinction, as small as that is.  You may have merely a different view of the concept.  The peak width of 5 means that any other candidate peak within 5 units will be considered part of the original peak, rather than a distinct maximum.  Thus, `width` gives a minimum distance between peaks.

Comment: Ahh i see. Seems like different ways of says the same thing. I am curious however why this is supplied as a list instead of just a threshold. I guess there are times for example you'd want to find peaks in groups of 5 and 7, but not 6? seems kind of odd to me.

Comment: Right; I haven't yet convinced myself either way.  I believe it's a list of two elements: min and max.